# ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS postgres systemd service

Tags: systemd, postgresql

I am installing Postgres 11 on Ubuntu 18.04. When you do a non-default install:

First install `postgresql-common`. Adapt the config file to NOT create main cluster , `start_conf= 'auto'` and `data_directory = '/pgs002/%v/%c'`

Install `postgresql-11`, `contrib` and `postgresql-11-postgis-2.5`
Then you create a cluster with `pg_createcluster`.

There are two problems:

1. The DB does not start. (because the `pg_hba_conf` etc are in `/etc/postgres`... and not in `/pgs002/11/cluster/data`).

   This is easy to fix, just copy the conf files to the right places.
2. The service is not created or not created in the correct way. There are two `postgresql` files in `/lib/systemd/system`, `postgresql.service` and `postgresql@.service`. The latter's file size is 1580, the former's 337. The latter seems to be correct, (contents of the file) but not the name. There is no service created for the cluster.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think I can answer my own question after some: when you create a PG cluster this way, you have to enable the service yourself: sudo systemctl enable postgresql@version-cluster name. 
After that, the symlinks are created and you can manage the instance with the service file.

Comment: [Read the doco about systemd that is in your `/usr/share/doc/postgresql-common/` directory.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/502800/5132)